# Is there a linked hash set in C++?

Tags: c++, set

Java has a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which is a set with a predictable iteration order. What is the closest available data structure in C++?

Currently I'm duplicating my data by using both a set and a vector. I insert my data into the set. If the data inserted successfully (meaning data was not already present in the set), then I push_back into the vector. When I iterate through the data, I use the vector.

Comment: `std::set` is ordered. Do you mean you want it to be in the same order you inserted it?

Comment: @sftrabbit, Yes, I want it in insertion order.

Comment: To really mimic this LinkedHashSet, you should use std::unordered_set + std::list, instead of std::set + std::vector.

Comment: If you store a pointer to the data, then you don't need to duplicate it.  If you care about removing items, I am not sure std::list has an O(1) remove like the LinkedHashSet probably has.

Comment: Perhaps if you give us more context we can come up with the C++-idiomatic solution to your underlying problems instead of trying to mimic Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can use it, then a [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) with `sequenced` and `hashed_unique` indexes is the same data structure as `LinkedHashSet`.

Failing that, keep an `unordered_set` (or `hash_set`, if that's what your implementation provides) of some type with a list node in it, and handle the sequential order yourself using that list node.

The problems with what you're currently doing (`set` and `vector`) are:

- Two copies of the data (might be a problem when the data type is large, and it means that your two different iterations return references to *different objects*, albeit with the same values. This would be a problem if someone wrote some code that compared the addresses of the "same" elements obtained in the two different ways, expecting the addresses to be equal, or if your objects have `mutable` data members that are ignored by the order comparison, and someone writes code that expects to mutate via lookup and see changes when iterating in sequence).
- Unlike `LinkedHashSet`, there is no fast way to remove an element in the middle of the sequence. And if you want to remove by value rather than by position, then you have to search the vector for the value to remove.
- `set` has different performance characteristics from a hash set.

If you don't care about any of those things, then what you have is probably fine. If duplication is the only problem then you could consider keeping a vector of pointers to the elements in the set, instead of a vector of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

To replicate `LinkedHashSet` from Java in C++, I think you will need two vanilla `std::map` (please note that you will get `LinkedTreeSet` rather than the real `LinkedHashSet` instead which will get O(log n) for insert and delete) for this to work.

- One uses actual value as key and insertion order (usually int or long int) as value.
- Another ones is the reverse, uses insertion order as key and actual value as value.

When you are going to insert, you use `std::map::find` in the first `std::map` to make sure that there is no identical object exists in it.

- If there is already exists, ignore the new one.
- If it does not, you map this object with the incremented insertion order to both `std::map` I mentioned before.

When you are going to iterate through this by order of insertion, you iterate through the second `std::map` since it will be sorted by insertion order (anything that falls into the `std::map` or `std::set` will be sorted automatically).

When you are going to remove an element from it, you use `std::map::find` to get the order of insertion. Using this order of insertion to remove the element from the second `std::map` and remove the object from the first one.

Please note that this solution is not perfect, **if you are planning to use this on the long-term basis**, you will need to "compact" the insertion order after a certain number of removals since you will eventually run out of insertion order (2^32 indexes for unsigned int or 2^64 indexes for unsigned long long int).
In order to do this, you will need to put all the "value" objects into a vector, clear all values from both maps and then re-insert values from vector back into both maps. This procedure takes O(nlogn) time.

If you're using C++11, you can replace the first `std::map` with `std::unordered_map` to improve efficiency, you won't be able to replace the second one with it though. The reason is that `std::unordered map` uses a hash code for indexing so that the index cannot be reliably sorted in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna know that std::map doesn't give you any sort of (log n) as in "null" lookup time. And using std::tr1::unordered is risky business because it destroys any ordering to get constant lookup time.

Try to bash a boost multi index container to be more freely about it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you described your combination of `std::set` and `std::vector` sounds like what you should be doing, except by using `std::unordered_set` (equivalent to Java's HashSet) and `std::list` (doubly-linked list). You could also use `std::unordered_map` to store the key (for lookup) along with an iterator into the list where to find the actual objects you store (if the keys are different from the objects (or only a part of them)).

The boost library does provide a number of these types of combinations of containers and look-up indices. For example, [this bidirectional list with fast look-ups example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#list_fast_lookup).