# Using a std::multimap, is it guaranteed that the begin() method returns the newest element?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, multimap, std

I am a novice of C++. I was wondering: if there is some insertion-time preservation in the iterators for `std::multimap` (C++11) collections?

I think, that, since it's indexed by an arbitrary value, there is no guarantee that the ordering of elements from an iterator preserves insertion time, but I am working on some code that makes a different assumption, i.e. that the element returned by `begin()` is related to insertion order.

Comment: From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap): _"The order of the key-value pairs whose keys compare equivalent is the order of insertion and does not change."_ then your assumption is right (starting with C++ 11) only if all keys are the same. If it doesn't satisfy your scenario you have to drop `multimap` in favor of (for example) `vector<tuple<K, vector<T>>>` (accepting it's linear search time).

Comment: does this mean that if the key is a string, then the pairs from the iterator will be sorted by the string and only if the strings are equal, by insertion order?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti does he? couldn't he, like, use a `map<vector<T>>`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant also `map` has same problem (elements are ordered by key comparison, they don't follow insertion order)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti No, I mean for values of the same key. (`multimap` also sorts its elements by key – I've just read the documentation, and the insertion-order guarantee is about values mapped to equal keys. This means that `map<K, vector<V>>` could be used in place of `multimap<K, V>`.)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you are looking for the LinkedHashMap equivalent of Java. A quick google search shows that there is a set with that capability in boost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799830/is-there-a-linked-hash-set-in-c . It may very well be the case that boost also contains such a map.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I understand, yes you may replace multimap<K, V> with map<K, vector<V>> (even if less efficient) but order isn't granted also for map

Comment: There are some ordering guarantees for equivalent elements in a `multimap`.  But I can't tell if they apply in your case.  English is so vague and ambiguous.  Got any C++ to share?

Answer (score 5):

Standard containers do not record/store insertion *times* themselves, but just within any group of elements with "equivalent" keys and since C++11, the insertion ordering is implied by where they're stored in the tree data structure used, and forward iteration will traverse them in the order that they were inserted.  I say "equivalent" because inside set/map/multiset/multimap, keys aren't compared with `==`; instead, they're considered "equivalent" if neither is less than the other, so you need only define `operator<` for the key type (it will use the default `<` operator for the key-type if you don't specify your own).

If you want insertion-ordered iteration across all elements in the container, then you have to use some manner of increasing series as the key - that could be timestamps or e.g. incrementing integers (or - a technically true but silly alternative - the entire table has to have elements with the same key, but if you're expecting that you should probably have used a `vector<>` or `list<>`).

Answer (score 2):

"Internally, the elements in a multimap are always sorted by its key following a specific strict weak ordering criterion indicated by its internal comparison object (of type Compare)."
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

So begin() should always give you the first element of the map, which is by default not ordered by insertion time.

EDIT:
I like the other answers, so it could be a good idea to write a new class, which derives from std:multimap. Then add a timestamp or int insertNr or id as a member variable and overwrite the compare-method!

Answer (score 1):

Based on *Tony D's* answer, one idea would be to use a *timestamp* for keys of a very small precision (miliseconds/nanoseconds etc). If you are using threads, you must apply a mechanism to ensure that two objects are not inserted in with the same timestamp (locking when inserting to the `std::multimap` etc).

UPDATE: If you are using the keys only for ordering reasons, other structures might be more appropriate for you, such as `std::list`.

Comment: I wonder why he has to use a multimap instead of a list if he wastes key just for ordering...

Comment: The question was about `multimap`, this is why I answered about it. A list might be a better solution, indeed. Answer updated based on your comment.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `multimap` does have the advantage of supporting find, lower and upper bound operations to find events at or around a specific time in O(log2N), while `list` would be O(N)....  (Thanks for your other comment about order of same-key elements - I hadn't realised that'd changed in C++11 - nice!)

Comment: @TonyD yes performance are an issue if you drop multimap, that's why I wrote _"...accepting it's linear search time..."_.

Comment: OK, I understood what you mean just now! yes performance are better with multimap if you need to search _around_ an insertion time.

Comment: Any improvement suggestion on the answer?